# Customizing url before adding to the Chromebook shelf

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

I am using a web application that remembers where I was as part of my account, across computers.

For instance, if on one computer I access this (example url):

```
http://example.com/app/area1/page1
```

And then on another computer access this:

```
http://example.com
```

it redirects automatically to the `/app/area1/page1` page.

So I'd like to add `http://example.com` to my shelf, but the only URL I'm allowed to add seems to be the current one in the address bar, which contains `/app/area1/page1`.

If I try to hit Escape before the page has redirected it seems Chrome detects the "did not fully load" scenario and doesn't show me the dialog for adding it to the shelf.

Can I edit the items on the shelf after adding them? Or is there a trick to get this, short of setting up a mock website that doesn't redirect and fiddling with DNS temporarily to fool Chrome?